# How to smooth animate between CardViews of different sizes?

Tags: android, animation, scale, android-cardview, viewanimator

### Background

I have only CardViews in a ViewAnimator (or anything else that would allow me to switch between CardViews), and I want to switch between them nicely, using scaling animation, so that it will look like a single CardView that changes its size.

### The problem

Each card has a different size and content, and some are generated dynamically , so it's problematic to set it all via XML.

### The question

Is there a built in way to do this?

Maybe not even use a ViewAnimator?

Or use a transition instead?

I just want to animate the cardViews. The content-switching will probably have a fade-in&out effects or no effects at all.

Is it maybe possible by using a single CardView and animate it?

Comment: Have you tried animating their `Rect`?

Comment: @NikolaDespotoski I don't understand. How do you do this?